# How to get the gray value of a color?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm using the code below to get a color, change it to gray scale and then save it. The problem is that it's always a blue tint and not gray.

```
newBitmapData = new BitmapData(bitmapWidth, bitmapHeight, true);

// Extract individual red, green, and blue values for the pixel:
rgbVal = bitmapData.getPixel(x, y);

redVal = (rgbVal & 0xFF0000) >> 16;
greenVal = (rgbVal & 0x00FF00) >> 8;
blueVal = rgbVal & 0x0000FF;


grayVal = Math.floor(0.3 * redVal + 0.59 * greenVal + 0.11 * blueVal);

newBitmapData.setPixel(x, y, grayVal);
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your "grayVal" is only its brightness, to make a color out of its brightness do:

```
newBitmapData.setPixel(x, y, Math.min(255,uint(grayVal))*0x10101);
```

Answer (score 0):

You didnt shift the red and green back again:

```
redVal = (rgbVal & 0xFF0000) >> 16;
greenVal = (rgbVal & 0x00FF00) >> 8;
blueVal = rgbVal & 0x0000FF;

//shift red and green back to original positions
redVal = int(0.3*redVal)<<16;
greenVal = int(0.59*greenVal)<<8;

grayVal = Math.floor(redVal + greenVal + 0.11*blueVal);
```